# Matching setState interval with css animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I am rotating the items in an array of images inside an interval of 5 seconds. Then I have a css animation with styled components that eases in the gallery images with a fade that occurs at the same time interval.

```
const fadeIn = keyframes`
  5%, 95% { opacity: 1 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
`
export const Gallery = styled.div<{ lapse: number }>`
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1064px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ${fadeIn} ease-in-out ${({ lapse }) => `${lapse}s`} infinite;
`
```

The problem is that when I change the `state` even thou at first it seems in sync, eventually the `setState` takes a bit longer

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([])

// Time in seconds for each image swap, fading in between
const lapse = 5
...

useEffect(() => {
  // Clone the images array
  const imgs = [...images]
        
  // Time interval same as css animation to fade in
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    // Take the first element and put it at the end
    imgs.push(...imgs.splice(0, 1))
    // Update the state, this seems to desync as time passes
    setImages(imgs)
  }, lapse * 1000)

  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [images])
        

return (
  <Gallery lapse={lapse}>
    <Portal>
      <img src={imgs/${images[0]}`}
    </Portal>
    <Thumbnails>
      <Thumbwrapper> 
        <img src={imgs/${images[1]}`}
      </Thumbwrapper>
      <Thumbwrapper> 
        <img src={imgs/${images[2]}`}
      </Thumbwrapper>
     </Thumbnails>
  </Gallery>
)
```

Is there a way I can make sure the swapping happends smoothly?

[image]

Comment: Instead of updating the full arrays could you try to only store the index you want to display and update that index ?

Comment: The problem with that is that eventually the index runs out, and I have to reset to 0, the problem is that I have three images to display. So If the gallery has only three images (sometimes it happens), then nothing rotates

Comment: `index = (index + 1) % images.length`

Comment: But then on the interval of the property which is about a minute, these images would not rotate it would stay put cause there's only three images. What I need is that every three seconds it fades out a bit and the images rotate

Comment: Ok now it is clearer with the image you added. You want to see 3 images at the same time

Comment: Yes, every five seconds rotate right, the way I have done with `imgs.push(...imgs.splice(0, 1))` but is `setState` that sometimes takes longer and it swaps after the animation has happened

Comment: So you just want to change the position & width of the images every 3 seconds ?

Comment: Pretty much, the way I am doing it is by pointing the img src to `images[0]`, `images[1]` and `images[2]` and changing the array order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that having two 'clocks' to keep the time, one being react setState and the other css animation, was at the core of the problem.

So I am now keeping a single interval with a setTimeout to make sure it goes in order then substract the time taken on the timeouts from the interval and toggle the class for css

```
export const Gallery = styled.div<{ fadeIn: boolean }>`
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1064px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: ${({ fadeIn }) => (fadeIn ? 1 : 0)};
`
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([])
const [fadeIn, setFadeIn] = useState<boolean>(true)

useEffect(() => {
  let interval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>
  if (images.length) {

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setFadeIn(false)

      setTimeout(() => {
        setImages(images => images.slice(1).concat(images[0]) )
        setFadeIn(true)
      }, 400)
    }, (lapse - 0.4) * 1000)
  }
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [images])

const getImage = (i: number) =>  <img src={imgs/${images[i]}`} />

<Gallery fadeIn={fadeIn}>
  <Portal>{getImage(0)}</Portal>
  <Thumbnails>
    <Thumbwrapper>{getImage(1)}</Thumbwrapper>
    <Thumbwrapper>{getImage(2)}</Thumbwrapper>
  </Thumbnails>
</Gallery>
```

I did however used @Nice Books better `setState` aproach

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if we can have example in codesandbox. Also I would like to ask you, maybe I am missing something, but how do you determine when to stop using effect, since it depends on `image`, which is, I assume, part of the useSate hook, and in that same effect you are updating that same `image`, which will lead to another effect usage(leading to infinity loop)?

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I made similar example on codesandbox to look it on my own. It looks to me that main problem here is sync between applied CSS and actual update in your react component. When using setInterval with 5000ms it does not mean that it will be triggered right after 5000ms, but CSS animation on the other side is always right on time, so it stuck when two of those become unsynced.
It looks like the only way to solve this is to recreate `img` elements on each reorder, by introducing timestamp state and use it as part of the each `img` key in order to force `img` recreation on each update. Also you would need to change animation in simpler way.

CSS would besomething like this:

```
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

.image {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1064px;
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And functional component would be something like this(hook part only):

```
      const [images, setImages] = useState(["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]);
      const [dateTimeWhenChanged, setDatetimeWhenChanged] = useState("");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const imgs = [...images];
    
        // Time interval same as css animation to fade in
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          // Take the first element and but it to the end
          imgs.push(...imgs.splice(0, 1));
          // Update the state, this seems to desync as time passes
          setImages(imgs);
          setDatetimeWhenChanged(new Date().toString());
        }, 5 * 1000);
        
         return (
    <div>
      {images.map((img, ind) => (
        <img
          key={`${ind}-${dateTimeWhenChanged}`}
          alt={img}
          src={`images/${img}`}
          className="imgg"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I never ends, it's supposed to cycle on a loop. When the `images` array is ready, I just want to cycle the array by rotating the order of the items

Comment: Ah, okay, I got it. So it was intentionally because that is your use case.

Comment: I wanted to add reply to your post but since I am 0 day old on stackoverflow(not enough score) I will write it here. Can you explain why solution that Weedoze suggested does not work for you? It seems that in your use case, when you have one primary image(on top) and few others below it would make sense just to modify index for that primary image and nothing else. You would have extra useState for that "primaryIndex" and in setInterval you should update only index, nothing else. Then in render part you would have top part as images[primaryIndex], and below that render rest of them.

Comment: Yeah but when you change the index for the first image to be the second and the second to be the third what would be the third then? if we have an array with `['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg']` we have now run out of indexes on the array. So of you reset to 0 nothing moves

Comment: Any opinion on my updated answer?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in my case, I do not want to loop with a map, I want to render in different divs

Comment: You can use it as you wish in render part, I used with map just for simplicity of demonstration. I also tested case with moving `images[0]` on top in separate div, and rest of them below that primary image(case like the one you provided, one up and others below).

Answer (score 0):

Make the component class based,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        interval: null,
        images: ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"],
        timeChanged: null
    };
}

// setInterval when component is mounted
componentDidMount() {
    var interval = setInterval(()=> {
        // use callback argument for setState 
        // when new value (images) depends on old value
        this.setState((state)=>({
            timeChanged: (new Date()).toString(),
            images: state.images.slice(1).concat(state.images[0]) 
            // add 1st img at the end
        });
    }, 3000);
    this.setState({interval: interval});
}

// clearInterval before component is unmounted
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.interval);
}
```

When the state is updated using its old value the **callback argument** should be used.
(See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a portion of an array.

Also see [how to update state arrays in React](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/).

If you still wish to use hooks. Just call `setImages` with
`(images)=>images.slice(1).concat(images[0])`.
I'm not sure where the `clearTimeout` should be, when using hooks.

Comment: But my whole project uses ReacHooks

Comment: No issue. Just make this one a class. It won't impact the other components.

Comment: I would have to refactor a lot of other functions I have on the component, can it not be made with ReactHooks?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd like to see what kind of functions would be impacted by a hooks->class transition. Event listeners ?

Comment: Nothing would be affected I think but I'll have to change to a style I am not used to. Also out of curiosity is it possible with hooks?

Comment: I think you mean `slice` not `slices`. I have tested your approach and even thou is better than mine as in is faster still over time starts to loose sync with the animation. The solution I have posted thou is perfect sync